# Create cone geometry with rectangular base in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to create the Cone Geometry with rectangular base in three.js. How could I do that?

I'm providing the image here so that i can make some sense what I'm speaking.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cone with a square base is a specific case of a cylinder with 4 sides and one of the base radius equal to 0.

You can create generic cylinder with:

```
THREE.CylinderGeometry(radiusTop, radiusBottom, height, radiusSegments, heightSegments, openEnded)
```

A specific example would be:

```
THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 30, 80, 4, 1, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What could be the values I need to pass to create the above geometry? Simple line of example please.

Comment: var cylinderGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 30, 30, 80, 20, 4 ); gives normal hollow cylinder. But I want cone looks like above diagram. :)

Comment: THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 30, 80, 4, 1, true);

Comment: I'm very thankful for your help. I've one more question, which tip of the cone in the above diagram should place in -z axis so that rectangular base should face to the camera, also I request how could I set the depth so that cone could be viewed as it is rather just rectangle base is showing up.

Comment: Please do not add additional questions here. Please accept this answer, and if you have further issues, post a new question. If you want to view the cone differently, you have to either move the camera or rotate the cone. Your best bet is to try to learn by yourself by studying the examples -- without resorting to asking questions. There are a lot of three.js examples for you to study. I bet you can figure it out! :-)